# Class send through a CallBack function

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't figure out how to correctly use boost::bind while sending a class function as a callback Function. I want to callBack function to have on class I made as an argument as well.

Do far my code is like this :

```
    Scribe(ros::NodeHandle ao_nh, std::string topic, Platform& p) : _verbose(false), _topic_name(topic), _timeStamp(ros::Time::now()), _cmd(), _needChecking(false) {
    //Scribe mode
    _scribe=ao_nh.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>( topic,1000, boost::bind(&Scribe::callBackFunc, _1, &p), this);
    //Timer
    _bomb=ao_nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(2),&Scribe::bombCallBack, this);
};
```

and the call back function is like this :

```
void callBackFunc(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& msg, Platform* plat);
```

Or, I have a error such that `no matching function to call` and I can't figure out how to correctly declare the subscriber.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143196/class-send-through-a-callback-function/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally:

`boost::bind(&ClassName::classMethod, &class_instance, arg1, arg2, ...);`

So in this case, since const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& msg is passed in as _1:

`boost::bind(&Scribe::callBackFunc, this, _1, &p);`

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-22**:
Ok thanks, it worked !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`subscribe` has direct support for class members as callbacks. So I suggest making callBackFunc a method of class Platform and following the instructions in the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks

Edit: Ooops... didn't read properly, your callback is alreay member of class Scribe. Check out the answer by @paulbovbel and make sure to remove the last `this` paramter in the `subscribe` call, because you already supply it in via bind.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2